# Loading multiple images in MATLAB from a specific folder

Tags: matlab

***im trying to load a group of images to matlab to do some process over each, and here is my code:***

```
s=dir(fullfile('D:\Matlab\pics\dude2\*.jpg\')) % My specific destination
numel(s)
 for n=1:numel(s)
     load(s(n).name);
     % my processes over each image
 end
```

***but i got this errur:***

```
Error using load
Unable to read file 'PIC_0134.JPG': no such file
or directory.
```

where PIC_0134.JPG is a image exist in the file destination.

ANY HELP??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s(n).name` returns just the filename without the path. You have to append the name to the entire path before passing it to `load()`:

```
path = 'D:\Matlab\pics\dude2\';
s=dir(fullfile([path '*.jpg'])); 
numel(s)
for n=1:numel(s)
   img = imread([path s(n).name]);
   % your image processing
end
```

Comment: Plus there is a problem with `load` employed instead of ̀`imload`. See my answer to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519005/loading-multiple-bmp-images-in-matlab) of the same author.

Comment: Yes, of course. I did not notice that. I changed it. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, i checked that and it is actually `imread` (at least using my Matlab version).