# Loading multiple '.bmp' images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

***im trying to load a group of images with the extension'.BMP' to matlab to do some process over each, and here is my code:***

```
s=dir('*.jpg')
numel(s)
 for n=1:numel(s)
     load(s(n).name);
     % my processes over each image
 end
```

***but i got this errur:***

```
Error using load
Number of columns on line 3 of ASCII file
D:\Study\Memo_Master\Group Images
Comprission\Matlabs\1.bmp must be the same as
previous lines.
```

***where '1.bmp' is a image exist in the file destination.
ANY HELP??***

Comment: `s=dir('*.jpg')` will look for files with extension `.jpg` instead of `.BMP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load` function is aimed at loading mat-files (*i.e.* binary data files), not images. To load images, you should use the `imread` function instead.

In your code:

```
s = dir('*.bmp');
for n = 1:numel(s)

     Img = imread(s(n).name);

     % my processes over each image

end
```

Best,